# WPF Launch animation from code-behind in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, wpf-animation

I'm looking for the way to code-behind launch an animation on a control contained in an `ControlTemplate`.
In my app I have custom templated buttons (playing menu role) created from an `ObservableCollection` :

MainMenuViewModel :

```
/// <summary>
/// Menu items list
/// </summary>
private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _items;

....

/// <summary>
/// Menu items list property
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set { _items = value; }
}
```

MainMenuView :

```
<UserControl x:Class="OfficeTourismeBrantome.Views.MainMenuView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraLight" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEBEDEA" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding MenuLayout.MenuItemSize.Height}" />-->
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard Name="themeSelectionAnimation">
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="coloredRectangle"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                From="30.0" 
                                                To="250.0" 
                                                Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>                                    
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="False" >
                            <ContentPresenter Canvas.Left="{Binding MenuLayout.MenuItemLeftMargin}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                                  
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <TextBlock 
                                Text="{Binding SecondaryText}" 
                                Canvas.Top="50"
                                Canvas.Left="10"
                                FontSize="30"
                                FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                FontStyle="Italic"
                                Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                                />
                            <Rectangle
                                Canvas.Top="30"
                                Canvas.Left="10"
                                Name="coloredRectangle"
                                Width="30"
                                Height="10"
                                Canvas.ZIndex="0"
                                Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </Canvas>                        
                    </ControlTemplate>                    
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>             
        </Style>
        <Storyboard x:Key="themeUnselectionAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation                 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                From="250.0" 
                To="30.0" 
                Duration="0:0:0.15" />
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl Name="menuButtonContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="{Binding MenuLayout.MenuMargin}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>        
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button 
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MenuItemButtonStyle}" 
                    Margin="{Binding ElementName=menuButtonContainer, 
                                        Path=DataContext.MenuLayout.MenuItemMargin}"                    
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=menuButtonContainer, 
                                        Path=DataContext.MenuLayout.MenuItemSize.Height}"
                    Content="{Binding Text}"                    
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=menuButtonContainer, 
                                        Path=DataContext.ChangeThemeCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see in the code above, I got an animation automatically triggered on button click. I want to play it reverse when another button in the collection is clicked (another menu entry is selected). The animation to play is the one called themeUnselectionAnimation.

First question : is there a way to do it only in XAML? I'm not sure as another button need to be pressed to trigger it.

Below is what I thought :

1. In the `Button` (which is my menu item) command action, send a message to let subscribers that menu item is changing.
2. Register to it in `MainMenuView` code-behind.
3. Launch animation from there.

My problem so far is to set the target control for the animation. To do that, I need to find the `Rectangle` named `coloredRectangle` in `ControlTemplate`. How to do that ?

Here below is my code corresponding to above steps :

Step 1 : send message (I'm using MVVM Light framework)

```
/// <summary>
/// Delegates that handles theme change process and tasks
/// </summary>
/// <param name="themeId">the new active theme</param>
private void ChangeTheme(int themeId)
{
    // Set current active theme as inactive, if one is selected.
    // Exception use because of Single implementation that throw an InvalidOperationException if not item is found
    try
    {
        MenuItem currentTheme = Items.Single(x => x.IsActive == true);

        // Check if this is current theme. If it is, we do nothing.
        if(currentTheme.Id == themeId)
            return;

        // If current theme is set and new theme id is not the same, disable the old one
        currentTheme.IsActive = false;
        // Set new theme as active
        Items.Single(x => x.Id == themeId).IsActive = true;

        // Finally, launch unselection animation

        // Send message and register to it in view code behind
        // Create inner message
        ThemeChangeNotification innerMessage = new ThemeChangeNotification();
        innerMessage.NewThemeId = themeId;
        innerMessage.OldThemeId = currentTheme.Id;

        NotificationMessage<ThemeChangeNotification> message =
            new NotificationMessage<ThemeChangeNotification>(innerMessage, "");
        // Send message
        Messenger.Default.Send(message);                
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
        // Set first theme selection as active
        Items.Single(x => x.Id == themeId).IsActive = true;
    }                                    
}
```

Step 2 : Register to message

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<ThemeChangeNotification>>(this, ChangeThemeAnimation);
```

Step 3 : reach Button from index/id and launch animation (not working)

```
/// <summary>
/// Theme change message delegate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">The ThemeChangeNotification message</param>
private void ChangeThemeAnimation(NotificationMessage<ThemeChangeNotification> message)
{
    var buttonTheme = menuButtonContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(message.Content.OldThemeId) as FrameworkElement;
    var rectangle = buttonTheme.FindName("coloredRectangle") as Rectangle;
    Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("themeUnselectionAnimation") as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, rectangle);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Thank you very much for your answers !

Comment: There should definitely be a better (more direct) way, than the one you're attempting.  For example: have a property like "IsSelected" in the item view model -- and use a `DataTrigger` to trigger the animations in XAML.  Another example: use a re-templated `ListBox` instead of ItemsControl (since your control clearly needs the concept of item selection).

Comment: Thank you McGarnagle, the Trigger seems to be my best try. As you said also, I will use a re-templated ListBox. Thank for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, you can just create another `Style` based on the first one that uses the other `Storyboard` instead... then you could just apply the reverse `Style` on whichever `Button`(s) that you want to start that `Storyboard`:

```
<Style x:Key="ReverseMenuItemButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraLight" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEBEDEA" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Name="themeUnselectionAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="coloredRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                        From="30.0" 
                                        To="250.0" 
                                        Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>                                    
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>                    
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>             
</Style>
```

I've got to be fully honest... I didn't totally understand your question, so if that didn't answer it, it seems as though you also want to know how to start a `Storyboard` from a view model. In this case, you just need a `bool` property which will start the animation when set to `true` in the view model. You can do that using the `DataTrigger.EnterActions`:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBooleanPropertyInViewModel}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard ... />
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Again... I still don't really know what you're after... I'd suggest working on your question asking skills before posting another one. However, this much I could work out:

> You're getting an *TargetName cannot be used on Style Setter* error and you want to target your `coloredRectangle` element.

The usual fix for this error is simply to move your `Trigger` to the element that you are trying to target. So try this instead:

```
<Rectangle Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="10" Name="coloredRectangle" ... >
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard ... />
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan,Thank you very much for your answer. I'm a WPF newbie and it's true my post may be a bit long, but your second suggestion is very close to what I try to achieve. The only precision I need now is to know how to target my coloredRectangle inside the DataTemplate. When I try to use TargetName property, I got MC4011 error (TargetName cannot be used on Style Setter). Any suggestion? THanks !

Comment: I put it in the ControlTemplate.Triggers, and bind it my VM prop. I defined TargetName and TargetProperty: 
` <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="coloredRectangle"            
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"...` Not working. :(